# Frequency dependent frequency shift

Tags: frequency-response

I have the Fourier Transform or FFT of a signal, call it $F(f)$. I would like to apply a "frequency-dependent frequency shift" to it. Specifically, frequency $f$ should be shifted to $3f^2$, for all $f$. Physically, this signal is undergoing dispersion.

Say I have a signal of a one-dimensional wave (sound amplitude, water height, or voltage, etc.) as a function of time at a specific location, and I'm trying to estimate the spatial signal at a single instant in time. Let the dispersion relation be $k=3f^2$, where k is the wavenumber. This procedure will change the temporal signal to the spatial signal

This seems like a linear system to me, so how would I find the frequency response $H(f)$ of the system? Knowing the frequency response, I can simply multiply $F(f)$ by the $H(f)$ to find the resulting signal.

Comment: If a frequency becomes another frequency, that's not a linear system so there is no frequency response that will do what you want.

Comment: As Oli says, this system is not linear. Any input sine wave should appear at the output at the same frequency but different phase and amplitude if the system is linear.

Comment: Linear systems can shift frequencies. Time invariant linear systems cannot. So there's still no frequency response, but it's not linearity that's the problem here.

Comment: @TSJ, It's not really clear to me what it is that you're trying to achieve here. It has also nothing to do with dispersion as far as I can see. The usual meaning of dispersion requires a time and a spatial coordinate and a nonlinear relationship between temporal and spatial frequency. How does that apply to your question?

Comment: @Jazzmaniac Say I have a signal of a one-dimensional wave (sound amplitude, water height, or voltage, etc.) as a function of time at a specific location, and I'm trying to estimate the spatial signal at a single instant in time. Let the dispersion relation be $k=3f^2$, where $k$ is the wavenumber. This procedure will change the temporal signal to the spatial signal - would you agree?

Comment: @Jazzmaniac right, I meant LTI

Answer (score 1):

Before I try to answer the question, let's see how the question relates to dispersion.

The solution space of a dispersive (linear) wave equation in $n$ dimensions is spanned by the basis functions

$$f_{\mathbf{k}}(\mathbf{x},t) = \exp( i\, \omega(\mathbf{k}) t )\exp( i\, \mathbf{k}\cdot \mathbf{x} )$$

where $\mathbf{k} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is the spatial frequency vector or wave vector. The temporal frequency $\omega$ depends on the  wave vector, or just on its magnitude $|\mathbf{k}|$ if the dispersion is isotropic. If $\omega \propto |\mathbf{k}|$ we have the special case of no dispersion. We can also assume in general that $\omega\geq 0$ to simplify calculations.

The basis functions are orthonormal in the Dirac sense with respect to their spatial coordinate:

$$\langle f_{\mathbf{k}},f_{\mathbf{k'}}\rangle := \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f_{\mathbf{k}}(\mathbf{x},t)\, f_{\mathbf{k'}}(\mathbf{x},t)\, d\mathbf{x} = \delta(\mathbf{k}-\mathbf{k'})$$

And the general solution of the wave equation is:

$$f(\mathbf{x},t) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} c(\mathbf{k})\, f_{\mathbf{k}}(\mathbf{x},t)\, d\mathbf{k} $$

If we now observe that general solution at $\mathbf{x}=0$, we get the relationship

$$f(0,t) = \Re\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} c(\mathbf{k})\,\exp( i\, \omega(\mathbf{k}) t )\, d\mathbf{k}^n \right)$$

which looks similar to a Fourier transform of $c(\mathbf{k})$. If we can turn this into a proper Fourier transform, the inverse Fourier transform of the observation will give us the expansion coefficients $c(\mathbf{k})$ required for the reconstruction of the full spatial solution of the wave.

At this point, we need to make a few additional assumptions. The first one is that $n$ equals 1 so that the coefficients are also a function on $\mathbb{R}$. We also have to assume that the dispersion is isotropic and $\omega(|\mathbf{k}|)$ is differentiable and strictly monotonic.

This is not enough however. We also need to assume a direction of travel so that $\omega(|\mathbf{k}|)$ becomes an invertible function on a restriction of $k>0$ or $k<0$ respectively.

We pick a "right" travelling wave, so $k>0$. With this, we can change the integration variable with $dk=\frac{\partial k}{\partial\omega}\,d\omega$ to get

$$f(0,t) = \Re\left(\int_\mathbb{R_{\geq 0}} c(k(\omega)) \frac{\partial k(\omega)}{\partial\omega} \exp(i\,\omega t)\, d\omega \right)$$

where $k(\omega)$ is the inverse function of $\omega(k)$. Identifying

$$C(\omega) := c(k(\omega)) \frac{\partial k(\omega)}{\partial\omega}$$ for $\omega\geq 0$ and the complex conjugate for $\omega<0$, we can see that $f(0,t)$ is the Fourier transform of $C(\omega)$.

With the inverse Fourier transform we get

$$C(\omega) = \int_\mathbb{R}f(0,t) \exp(-i\,\omega t) dt$$

and consequentially

$$c(k(\omega)) = \frac{1}{k'(\omega)} \int_\mathbb{R}f(0,t) \exp(-i\,\omega t) dt$$

or simply

$$c(k) = \omega'(k) \int_\mathbb{R}f(0,t) \exp(-i\,\omega(k) t) dt$$

which we can express in terms of the inverse Fourier transform as

$$c(k) = \omega'(k)\,\mathcal{F_t}^{-1} \left\{ f(0,t) \right\}\left( \omega(k) \right) $$

Using this theoretical background we can now reconstruct the spatial wave function of a *free one-dimensional right travelling wave with open boundary conditions*.

In the expansion of the general wave solution from above we can substitute the $c(k)$ to get:

$$f(x,t)=\int_\mathbb{R} \omega'(k)\,\mathcal{F_t}^{-1} \left\{ f(0,t) \right\}\left( \omega(k) \right)\, \exp( i\, \omega(k) t )\exp( i\, k x ) dk $$

This can also be written as a Fourier transform in $k$:

$$f(x,t)= \mathcal{F_k}\left\{ \mathcal{F_t}^{-1} \left\{ f(0,t) \right\}\left( \omega(k) \right)\,\omega'(k)\,\exp(i\,\omega(k)\,t)\, \right\}(x)$$

This translates to the following algorithm for the reconstruction of the spatial wave function at time $t$:

1. Take the inverse Fourier transform of $f(0,t)$
2. Evaluate the result at $\omega(k)$
3. Multiply the result with $\omega'(k)$
4. Evolve the result in time by multiplying with $\exp(i\,\omega(k)\,t)$
5. Take the forward Fourier transform with respect to k

You can implement this in the discrete domain by taking regular grids for the variables $\omega$ and $k$ and use the discrete Fourier transform.

As you can see, it's a little more complicated than what you described, but your idea was going in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

The system is non-linear on $f$(requency) which can also be seen as "[rate of phase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency#Related_types_of_frequency)" for a sinusoidal component.

If it was 3*f, it would fall under @Peter.K's comment (above) and it would be realisable directly from [the shifting property of the Fourier Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Basic_properties).

But due to the [quadratic term](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_function) in $3 \cdot f^2$ this cannot be done with a Linear Time Invariant ([LTI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LTI_system_theory)) System (i.e. Oli's comment, above).

You could however work with linear segments (of the $3 \cdot f^2$) over sliding-window techniques ([this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overlap%E2%80%93add_method) or [that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overlap%E2%80%93save_method)) to produce something like [this](http://www.guitarpitchshifter.com/algorithm.html).

Hope this helps.

Comment: A_A, thanks - I'll look into the links and let you know of any issues that come up.

Comment: I'm afraid that this does not apply to the problem of the OP, which turned out to be quite different from pitch shifting.

Comment: That's absolutely fine, I learned something too.